Is it necessary to match the operating ranges of the two stages in a two-stage amplifier
I'm trying to design a two-stage amplifier as shown below. What confuses me is that - is it necessary to match the operating range of the two stages (ie. Vocm of the first stage is within the Vicm range of the second)?

Intuitively, the output of the first stage should fall into the green box in the figure below (which is the transfer function of a CS amplifier). If the output of the first stage always saturates the second stage (as in the red box), the gain will be very small and distorted. However, even though I hadn't done the 'matching', the amplifier worked fine in the TIA configuration. But when I look at the Vg7 when INN=INP=VCM in an open-loop configuration, Vg7 is not in the linear region (the green box).

Am I understanding this correctly? Or it is not necessary when the feedback is applied?

Please redo your image with a white background and remove all information that isn't absolutely necessary for this question. The detail you have around the transistors is mainly clutter.

I think I can answer your question, but I have to make sure a few things.
1, according to your M0-M6 ratio, your second stage have 10x quiescent current than first stage?
2, seems like your M4 M5 is very long, any specific reason?
To reduce systematic error, we usually make (W4+W5):W7 = W0:W6 and L4=L5=L7
I think your circuit will still work in feedback, but with more input referred offset.

Hi @WillisLin, thanks for your comment. Yes, the first stage is biased at 8uA, and the second at 80uA. I made M4 and M5 very long to get a larger gain, as I'm using a 130nm process (very low intrinsic gain). Do you think this works? I'll also try with the ratio you proposed to see the difference. Also, I'm looking forward to your answer!

@GeorgeGuo To make the gain large, your need both long PMOS and NMOS. Using only super long NMOS means the NMOS need a large Vgs, lowering its intrinsic gain.

@WillisLin I guess the gain=gm2*(ro2∥ro5)? where ro5=intrinsic_gain/gm5. So making the W5/L5 smaller, gm5 is smaller so ro5 is larger - means a larger gain? Is my understanding correct?

@GeorgeGuo I can't say this is wrong. But according to your W L ratio, your ro5 might be over 10 times ro2, making your gain approximately equal to gm2×ro2. Super long M4 and M5 will slow down your opamp.

@WillisLin I get your point. Thanks so much!

@GeorgeGuo Your welcome.
